# Phase transition 2D Ising model magnetization around critical temperature

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition

I am stuck on a part in the derivation of the critical exponent of the magnetization in case of the 2D Ising model. I know that I should find $M \propto (T_c-T)^{1/8}$ but I am having some trouble finding this.

I used the following expression for the magnetization $T<T_c$:

$$M = M_{max}(1-\sinh^{-4}(2\beta J))^{\frac{1}{8}}.$$

This equation is from Yoshioka. I did the following derivation around $T_c$.

$$\sinh^{-4}(2\beta J) = \sinh^{-4}(\frac{2}{2.27}\frac{T_c}{T}),$$

where I used that $T_c \approx \frac{2.27 J}{k_B}$.

$$y \equiv \frac{2T}{2.27 T_c}\approx 0.88 \frac{T_c}{T},$$

$$\sinh^{-4}(0.88\frac{T_c}{T}) = \sinh^{-4}(y).$$

Now I used that $y \equiv 0.88 \frac{T_c}{T}$ is around $0.88$ at the critical temperature and therefore I used an expansion around this point:

$$\sinh^{-4}(y)\approx 1-5.7(y-0.88) = 1-a(\frac{T_c}{T}-1),$$

where $a$ absorbed the $0.88$. From this I derived that:

$$M \approx M_{max}(1-(1-a(\frac{T_c}{T}-1)))^{1/8} = M_{max}a^{1/8}(\frac{T_c}{T}-1)^{1/8}.$$

But note that we now get:

$$M \propto (\frac{T_c-T}{T})^{1/8}.$$

Could somebody spot the mistake in my calculation? Thanks in advance.

*Edit*:

Using the hint I defined:

$$1+u = \frac{T}{T_c}.$$

This gives the following results which are stated below.

$$\sinh^{-4}(\frac{0.88}{1+u})\approx 1+5.02u+9.06u^2+...$$

From this result one derives the critical exponent as follows:

$$M = M_{max}[1-(1+5.02u+9.06 u^2+...)]^{1/8} \approx M_{max}(-5.02u)^{1/8} \propto (T_c-T)^{1/8},$$

where we used $$-u = \frac{T_c-T}{T_c}.$$

**Note**: I edited this answer also for other users who might encounter the same problem, so I hope this is also useful for others. The lesson is that we way we expand functions does matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From this I derived that:
>
> $$M \approx M_{max}(1-(1-a(\frac{T_c}{T}-1))) = M_{max}a(\frac{T_c}{T}-1).$$

You need to raise the factor multiplying $M_{\text{max}}$ to the power $\dfrac{1}{8}$.

Comment: I adapted my question. Indeed there was a power missing, but this is not the crucial mistake in the calculation. The part that is peculiar is that I get $\frac{T_c-T}{T}$ instead of $\frac{T_c-T}{T_c}$. Do you see this flaw somewhere?

Comment: @dani there is no mistake in the math, it's just that you assume $T<T_c$ while you need to consider $T>T_c$, but formally that doesn't matter as you can absorb $(-1)^{1/8}$ in $a$.  The $1/T$ instead of $1/T_c$ is an artifact of the expansions, to leading order $T = T_c$. It's best to write $T = T_c (1+u)$ to eliminate $T$ and expand in powers of $u$ to make all of this more transparent. Obviously there are also going to be higher order analytical corrections to the leading exponent...

Comment: I worked it out and it did work. The only question I have is: why does the expansion with $u$ work? I can see it is way more handy than what I used before but it seems a bit odd to me that the way we give variables names gives a different approximation. The $(-1)^{1/8}$ I could include in the definition of $u$ so I used $-u = \frac{T_c-T}{T_c}$ that was not difficult indeed. At the moment it seems like a forced derivation since we knew which result we wanted to obtain, I hope you understand me.. Thanks for your previous answers anyway :)